# ChartJS, trying to make a button which changes the chart type from this code I have already prewritten:

Tags: javascript, button, charts, chart.js

How can I create a button that would change the data type for my chart from this code:

```
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "bar",
          data: {
            labels: this.dateList,
            datasets: [
              {
                type: 'bar',
                label: "Temperature",
                backgroundColor: "teal",
                borderColor: "black",
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                data: this.temperatureList
              }
            ]
          }
        })
```

Apologies if this question is too simple, I seem to have my head stuck around it atm.
The selection table is in this form:

```
<h5 class="label" id="">Chart Type</h5>
                    <select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChartType()">
                      <option value="line">Line</option>
                      <option value="bar">Bar</option>
                      <option value="radar">Radar</option>
                      <option value="polarArea">Polar Area</option>
                      <option value="doughnut">Doughnut</option>
                    </select>
```

I have tried using things like:

```
        function updateChartType() {
   myChart.destroy();
   myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: document.getElementById("chartType").value,
   });
};
```

alongside something like this:

```
      const line = document.getElementById('line');
      const bar = document.getElementById('bar');
      const pie = document.getElementById('pie');

      line.addEventListener('click', changechartline);
      bar.addEventListener('click', changechartbar);
      pie.addEventListener('click', changechartpie);


        function changechartline(){
          const updatetype = 'line';
          this.chart.type = updatetype;
          this.chart.update();
        }

        function changechartbar(){
          const updatetype = 'bar';
          this.chart.type = updatetype;
          this.chart.update();
        }

        function changechartpie(){
          const updatetype = 'pie';
          this.chart.type = updatetype;
          this.chart.update();
        }
```

with the buttons being :

```
      <button onclick="changeChart('line')" class="buttonhotline" style="vertical-align:middle" > Line </button>
      <button onclick="changeChart('bar')"  class="buttonhotbar"  style="vertical-align:middle" > Bar </button>
      <button onclick="changeChart('pie')"  class="buttonhotpie"  style="vertical-align:middle" > Pie </button>
```

Comment: having a look to the code, the updateChartType is creating a new chart only with the type, no data and no options.

Comment: the data is extracted from json files, forgot to add that